# Derivative with mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to understand a proof in a book but there is a statement in the proof and I'm not really sure whether my reasoning is correct or not.
Let $f$ be a strict convex $C^2(\mathbb{R})$ function and we define $s(x):= \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ with $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $z \in  \mathbb{R}$ with $z>y$. Then it is stated that $s'(x)=\alpha f''(\xi)$ for some $\alpha >0$ and $\xi$ between $y$ and $z$.

I know that with the mean value theorem we get $f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ for a $\xi \in (y,x)$. So we have $s'(x)=f''(\xi)$ with $\xi \in (y,x)$. But how do I get the bigger intervall $(y,z)$ and where does $\alpha$ come from? Are we simply making the intervall bigger and since $f$ is strict convex in $\mathbb{R}$ we have $f''>0$ and thus we can find a strictly positive $\alpha$ so that the statement is correct?

Comment: it is not true that $f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\implies f''(\xi)=s'(x)$ because $f'(\xi)$ is a number, not a function

Comment: "define $s(x):= \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$" how can a function of $x$ equal a function of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to shorten the question because I thought it comes down to the same problem but I see now that it doesn't.

Comment: In the proof $u$ is a weak solution of a conservation law. We consider a smooth curve $S: t \mapsto (\sigma(t),t)$ which devides the half-space $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R^+}$ in $M_l$, which corresponds to the left side of the curve, and $M_r$, the right side. We define $u_l:=u|_{M_l} \in C^1(\overline M_l)$ and $u_r:=u|{M_r} \in C^1(\overline M_r)$. We then consider $u$ on the curve and define $s(u):=\frac{f(u)-f(u_r)}{u-u_r}$. Now it is stated that $s'(u)=\alpha f''(\xi)$ with $\alpha>0$ and $\xi$ between $u_r$ and $u_l$.